# UDev automounting drives as 'usbhd' regardless of type and name on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, udev, automounting

I have 3 drives which I use for storage on my system. Here are their mounting points in `/etc/fstab`

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=f3cfbb3a-5014-4e0a-9b9d-ef4fde8f4031 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=9322c5b4-9157-49ab-b890-0b8d909b416f none            swap    sw              0       0

#store1
UUID=a2d57cda-515c-43e1-8d93-4f0d8714b713 /media/store1 ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
#store2
UUID=4f6bc0a9-5c9f-413b-9f8b-dc95e5a9462b /media/store2 ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
#store3
UUID=bb214693-06bc-412f-a7f9-b60bf7618fc5 /media/store3 ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

For some reason, Ubuntu is automounting the drives again as the `usbhd-*` naming convention.

```
/dev/sda5 on /media/store1 type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb3 on /media/store2 type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/store3 type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/usbhd-sdc1 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/usbhd-sdb1 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb3 on /media/usbhd-sdb3 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

My `/etc/udev/rules.d/media-by-label-auto-mount.rules` contains

```
# Start at sdb to avoid system harddrive.
KERNEL!="sd[b-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

# Import FS infos
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"

# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"

# Global mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"
# Filesystem-specific mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"

# Mount the device
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"

# Clean up after removal
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"

# Exit
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

Which I thought meant it ignored `/dev/sd*` drives.

Any ideas on how I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this rule correctly:

```
# Start at sdb to avoid system harddrive.
KERNEL!="sd[b-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

It's saying that if the device does not equal (`!=`) `sdb0`, `sdb1`, etc. then go to the label `"media_by_label_auto_mount_end"`.

So it would seem to be working correctly to me.

What if you do this?:

```
KERNEL="sd[b-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

Or you could put a rule before the existing `KERNEL!=` which matches whatever `sd*` drives you want and have that goto a label after the `"media_by_label_auto_mount_end"` label. From that point you could create any rules you want like this:

```
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="myusbhd-%k"
```

Comment: Now you mention it, I'm not sure why it's telling udev to mount everything in sd* and to ignore everything else. I don't believe I've changed that rule. I will reboot the server shortly and let you know.